# SQL function returns a single record. How to refactor SELECT query to use multiple records

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, for-loop, join

The following query has a SQL function with a parameter being passed from a `SELECT` statement. At the same time, that `SELECT` statement has `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses that use the record returned by function `my_func`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(pId bigint) RETURNS TABLE (table2_id bigint, column_1 bigint, field text) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT table2_id, table3_id, column_1, field 
    FROM t_name
  LEFT JOIN t2_name on t_name.key = t2_name.key
  WHERE t2_name.pId = pId
    ORDER BY table2_id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT column_1, column_2,
FROM table_name 
LEFT JOIN table2_name ON table2_name.table2_id = (SELECT rec.table2_id FROM my_func(table_name.column_1))
WHERE column_1 = (SELECT rec.column_1 FROM my_func(table_name.column_1))
AND table2_name.field = (SELECT rec.field FROM my_func(table_name.column_1))
GROUP BY column_1, column_2
ORDER BY column_1 ASC, column_2;
```

This works perfectly since `my_func` has a `LIMIT 1` statement that works well with the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clause in the query above. However, requirements changed and now I need to remove `LIMIT` so that `my_func` returns multiple records.

I could remove the `LIMIT 1` statement in the function, and change the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clause to look as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN table2_name ON table2_name.table2_id IN (SELECT rec.table2_id FROM my_func(table_name.column_1))
WHERE column_1 IN (SELECT rec.column_1 FROM my_func(table_name.column_1))
AND table2_name.field IN (SELECT rec.field FROM my_func(table_name.column_1))
```

**All I did** was replace the `=` symbol with `IN`. However, even though this works, it is not solving what I'm trying to achieve, because it creates an exponential query for every result in the `LEFT JOIN` and every result in the first `WHERE` clause and every result in the `AND` WHERE clause. Clearly, not what I want.

I thought about using a `FOR LOOP` as a solution

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  rec record;
BEGIN
FOR rec IN (SELECT table2_id, table3_id, column_1, field 
    FROM t_name
  LEFT JOIN t2_name on t_name.key = t2_name.key
  ORDER BY table2_id DESC) 
LOOP
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
      SELECT column_1, column_2,
      FROM table_name 
      LEFT JOIN table2_name ON table2_name.table2_id = rec.table2_id
      WHERE column_1 = rec.column_1
      AND table2_name.field = rec.field
      GROUP BY column_1, column_2
      ORDER BY column_1 ASC, column_2;
END LOOP
END;
$$
```

It was okay to remove `pId` from the previous function cause that was not critical. But now I'm getting errors:

> ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function

Any ideas on how to achieve this? In a nutshell, the function worked fine when a single record was returned (forced by `LIMIT 1`) but not sure how to refactor the whole thing for multiple records. Thanks.

Comment: Would that make a difference if you used exists instead? It may be that you are matching on NULL value.

Comment: OK maybe you should gıve sample data and desıred output. My guess, people will not be interested in queries done using names like field, column_1, column_2 ... BTW your query in function is implicitly an inner join although you have left join there, because of the where.

Comment: And BTW actually that function wouldn't compile. I understand you made typos while trying to use weird names like field, column_1 ... but that hides things all by itself.

Comment: And what is another_table? Are you really sure that your code looks like that?

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the suggestion! I'll make changes to the query in the post later today for clarity. But yeah, the function compiles just fine.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CetinBasoz made a good point on `LEFT JOIN` that is actually an `INNER JOIN`. Based on that and also the fact that you can compare [whole rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) in the `IN` expression, you can simplify your function and query like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(pId bigint) RETURNS TABLE (table2_id bigint, column_1 bigint, field text) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY 
  SELECT table2_id, column_1, field 
  FROM t_name
  -- LEFT Join can be commented out, since you have condition on t2_name in the WHERE clause below
  -- LEFT 
  JOIN t2_name 
  on t_name.key = t2_name.key
  WHERE t2_name.pId = pId

-- Below two lines can be commented out, since they don't make sense 
--    ORDER BY table2_id DESC
--    LIMIT 1;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT column_1, column_2
FROM table_name 
-- Here also, LEFT Join can be commented out, since you have condition on my_func in the WHERE clause below
-- LEFT 
JOIN table2_name 
ON (table2_name.table2_id, column_1, table2_name.field) 
    in (
      SELECT table2_id, column_1, field FROM my_func(table_name.column_1)
      -- this is for your previous logic, with limiting to 1 record, for testing:
      -- ORDER BY table2_id DESC
      -- LIMIT 1
    )
GROUP BY column_1, column_2
ORDER BY column_1 ASC, column_2;
```

**Update**
I completely overlooked the last query, where `pId` is removed. This way the function `my_func` is not required at all, and the final query can be simplified as:

```sql
SELECT column_1, column_2
FROM (
    SELECT table2_id, table3_id, column_1, field 
      FROM t_name
    LEFT JOIN t2_name on t_name.key = t2_name.key
  ) rec
JOIN table_name on table_name.column_1 = rec.column_1
JOIN table2_name 
   on table2_name.table2_id = rec.table2_id
  and table2_name.field = rec.field
GROUP BY column_1, column_2
ORDER BY column_1 ASC, column_2;
```

Comment: This is helpful @qaziqarta. So is the subquery in the join also replacing the `WHERE` and `AND` clauses?

Comment: I think this is the right approach, I'm making changes based on your answer. But how can I keep the WHERE clause in the query and why did you remove it?

Comment: @chris, do you mean the WHERE from the query, not from the function? Yes, I removed it because the condition could be moved to the join clause. Why do you want to keep the WHERE clause? If there are more conditions there, then you can keep them, I just moved the conditions for the `my_func` function.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I see your last Update to the answer. This clarified everything

Comment: @chris, yes, glad it helped. And later on you can join other tables in the same fashion. I think the confusion here is "procedural vs declarative" approach. I.e., in the description of the question all the queries try to operate on each record separately, either in loop or functions or via subqueries. For sql-problems, it's much easier to think in terms of sets. I.e. "what properties should my final data have", or "what common properties should my join tables exhibit", etc.